# Searches without rewrite (/?s=query) are better for SEO?

Tags: url, search, mod-rewrite

Is rewriting searches from:

```
/?s=query
```

to

```
/search/query
```

a bad idea for SEO?

I'm currently rewriting them for a cleaner URL but I discovered I cannot add them to Google Analytics. Does it also affect SEO? Is it a bad idea to rewrite them to mask the passed variable? Why?

Comment: Search results turning up in search results is very annoying for the user anyways. Only content pages should be indexed. Just set them to no-index :P

Comment: Is it a good idea to set them to no-index? wouldn't I lose potential visits?

Comment: Perhaps, but you certainly would make the web a better place. I'm usually annoyed when I run into one of those, and leave the site within 30 secs.

Comment: mmmm yes. I think I'll rather keep the visits and make a donation to the human fund